# Issue with group by with list aggregation

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In a query with `listagg()` I am trying to add a clause for split_rep: existence of `user_id` that has `profile_type='Split'`, and for multi_rep: existence of `user_id` with more than one `ap.id`.

Simplified query (where the -- is what I am trying to do):

```
select distinct r.user_id,
listagg(distinct ap.rep_code, ', ') within group (order by ap.bill_rate) as rep_code_list
--,case when max(ap.profile_type) over (partition by r.user_id)='Split' then 1 else 0 end has_split_rep_code
--,case when count(ap.id) over (partition by r.user_id)>1 then 1 else 0 end has_multi_rep_code 
from representatives r
join profiles ap on r.user_id=ap.user_id
group by r.user_id
```

This throws an error that `profile_type` and `id` need to be in `group by` - however if added, that would give the wrong output. Not sure why a window function is not supported with listagg, but any idea how to bypass that?

Sample data:

```
user_id   id   profile_type   rep_code
A         A    Self           AAA
A         B    Self           AAB
B         C    Self           AAC
C         D    Self           AAD
C         E    Split          AAE
D         F    Split          AAF
```

Desired output:

```
user_id   rep_code    split_rep_code   multi_rep_code
A         AAA, AAB    0                1
B         AAC         0                0
C         AAD, AAE    1                1
D         AAF         1                0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OVER`:

```
select distinct r.user_id,
  listagg(distinct ap.rep_code, ', ') within group (order by ap.bill_rate)
   over(partition by ap.user_id) as rep_code_list
  -- rest of cols
from representatives r
join profiles ap on r.user_id=ap.user_id;
```

Comment: Apparently Redshift DOES support over()! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html

Comment: Side note: Redshift is actually a fork of Postgres, not Oracle, so comparing to Oracle does not make much sense.

Comment: @user8834780 It looks I got old doc version. Great to hear it works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My comparison was about specific function `LISTAGG with DISTINCT + OVER`. As far as I know PostgreSQL has `string_agg` instead.

Comment: No worries bro :-) ... but if you keep in kind that Redshift is similar to Postgres, it might help you on other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confounding the purpose of `select distinct` when you use it with `group by`.  Each of these can do similar things, depending on the context.  I use a `CASE` expression below to compute the `split_rep_code` column, and I also added logic for the `multi_rep_code` column.

```
select
    r.user_id,
    listagg(ap.rep_code, ', ') within group (order by ap.bill_rate) as rep_code_list,
    case when sum(case when ap.profile_type = 'Split' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
         then 1 else 0 end as split_rep_code,
    case when min(ap.id) <> max(ap.id) then 1 else 0 end as multi_rep_code
from representatives r
inner join profiles ap
    on r.user_id = ap.user_id
group by
    r.user_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that the demo is in Postgres, and I used `string_agg` instead of Redshift's `list_agg`, but the principle is the same.  Also note that Redshift does not support using `DISTINCT` inside `list_agg`.  If you really need that behavior, you may have to subquery to remove duplicates first.

Comment: Redshift does support distinct inside listagg :) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I do hate group by since my select statement is always extremely complex, with aliases and case statements, so Lukasz's answer works better for me and was posted first

Comment: It is missing several columns you asked for, but I can't control who you mark correct, so go with that answer if you want.

Comment: The -- columns I had in the original query work perfectly with `listagg() over()`